# modify the kernel version information in the menuconfig

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I downloaded the kernel source and by typing the following command

```
make menuconfig
```

I can see the linux kernel version is ***3.02.02*** for example.

However, due to some reasons, I have to change it to say...

***3.01.01-12-generic***

I found the appending option in the menuconfig but this does not meet my need.

Please let me know if this is doable and how to rename it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the `Makefile` in the main directory and manually change the following variables:

```
VERSION = 
PATCHLEVEL = 
SUBLEVEL = 
EXTRAVERSION =
```